# Smallest numbers whose square has even number of digits

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, floating-point

```
4, 32, 317, 3163, 31623, 316228, 3162278, 31622777, 316227767, 3162277661, 31622776602, 316227766017, 3162277660169, 31622776601684, 316227766016838, 3162277660168380, 31622776601683794, 316227766016837934, 3162277660168379332, 31622776601683793320, 316227766016837933200, 3162277660168379331999, 31622776601683793319989, 316227766016837933199890, ...
```

Or in other words: given *n* output the *(n * 2)*-th term of [OEIS A017936](https://oeis.org/A017936): smallest number whose square has n digits.

Essentially we removed powers of 10 from mentioned OEIS serie.

## Notes

As noted by  [Neil](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil), there is a correlation with the digits of √(1/10), or even 10, 1 or any power of 10.
He also explained: *the length of integers increases at each power of 10. The length of squares of integers increases at (the ceiling of) each power of √10. Half of these powers are also powers of 10, while the other half are powers of 10 multiplied by √(1/10).*

Additionally a proof was given by [jjagmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/571433/jjagmath).
*If *n* is the number where the square change from having *k* digits to \$k+1\$ digits then \$(n-1)^2<10^k\le n^2\$.
So \$n-1 < 10^{k/2}\le n\$.

If *k* is even we have \$n = 10^{k/2}\$.

If \$k = 2m+1\$ then \$n-1 < 10^{m+1}\sqrt{1/10}< n\$ which explains why the first digits of *n* coincide with  \$\sqrt{1/10}\$.*

**More notes**

- There is a difference between the last digit and the corresponding digit in \$\sqrt{1/10}\$, e.g. for the 5th term:

```
5th term     31623 
√(1/10)    0.31622776601..
                 ↑
```

- Formal formula from OEIS A017936: *a(n) = ceiling(10^((n-1)/2))* which includes powers of 10 terms.
- The next term of *x* is between *\$(x-1) * 10\$* and *\$x * 10\$*

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), all usual golfing rules apply.

This is also [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) so you can output:

- *n*-th element
- first *n* terms
- infinite sequence

**[Floating point issues](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20533/84844) are allowed.**
However answers that doesn't fail due to floating point issues are encouraged, you can post both solutions so that we'll see the difference, in that case please post best score as main solution and the other as alternative indicating both scores.

I could fork the challenge in two separate questions but..   I think duplicating is annoying and doesn't make much sense.
At the same time, considering what @Bubbler stated in the FP issues consensus: *"Allowing or disallowing such functions (and intermediate floating point values) has a huge consequence, to the point that I could say it defines the actual challenge"*, I think it may be interesting to have a kind of challenge inside the challenge between FP issues in the same language.

---

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24608/84844)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 26 bytes

```
lambda n:int(10**(n-.5))+1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuha7chJzk1ISFfKsMvNKNAwNtLQ08nT1TDU1tQ0hCvan5RcpVChk5ikUJealp2oY6phqWhUUgVSnaVRoakJULVgAoQE)

Has floating-point issues.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 45 bytes

```
f=lambda n,i=1:10*100**n>i*i and f(n,i+1)or i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwFET3PcVfJtFKshC0EFcew020iX5ofkqSQnsWNwHRO3kbA3VgmMXjzfMzLvkRqLycvryn7NrDt3V6MP7aG6AtatUpKZSUQtAJBYKhHhyrZKN4iIB_6Yx-DDFDWlJTu0s2R3ubYsJAA3rM7FjDG1edGZAgGrpbtufdGJEyc2zmfP0qZd0f)

Suboptimal - this is kind of an intermediary solution that shows another way of proving the formula. (I came up with this before seeing the formula, and once I saw the formula I noticed the connection)

Here is something of a derivation:

1. Convert the loop-based solution (see below) to a recursive version:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:n*2>len(str(i*i))and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
2. Replace `len(str())` with a logarithmic computation \$ \lfloor\log(i^2) + 1 \rfloor \$:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:n*2>floor(log10(i*i)+1)and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
3. It's an integer comparison, so the `floor` can be removed:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:n*2>log10(i*i)+1and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
4. Raise both sides of the comparison as a power of `10`:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:10**(n*2)>10**(log10(i*i)+1)and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
5. Simplify:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:100**n>i*i*10and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
6. Due to an off-by-one error, the answer I arrived at had `10*` on the wrong side of the comparison; this is negated by choosing to use zero-indexed input (which is what I did instead of fixing the off-by-one error, because I'm lazy)

   At this point we have my intermdiate answer:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:10*100**n>i*i and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
7. Square root both sides of the comparison:

   ```
   f=lambda n,i=1:sqrt(10)*10**n>i and f(n,i+1)or i
   ```
8. Noting that the recursive wrapper now just searches for the first integral satisfying value of `i`, so it's pointless and can be replaced by `floor` `+1`:

   ```
   lambda n:floor(sqrt(10)*10**n)+1
   ```
9. Some Python-specific tweaks to get a more optimal final answer:

   ```
   lambda n:int(10**(n-.5))+1
   ```

   This is now just the 26-byter above!

I'm tired, so there are probably a bunch of mistakes in this derivation, but they mirror my tired and mistake-ridden thought process!

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```
n=i=input()
while`i*i`[-n:n]:i+=1
print i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHG8ozMnFQFQyuF1IrUZAUlJaWlpSVpuhY3NfNsM20z8wpKSzQ0ucCKEjK1MhOidfOs8mKtMrVtDbkKijLzShQyIRoWw7UuWG7IZcRlzGUC4QIA)

Completely non-formulaic solution.

-4 bytes with a cool slicing trick thanks to loopy walt.

-4 thanks to dingledooper

Comment: 45 for bottom solution: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN3VTUtMU0jTydDJtDTWtuBTKMzJzUhMytTITonXzrPJirTK1bQ25FAqKMvNKFDIhmnak5RcpVChk5ikUJealp2oY6phqWqVpVGhCpGFmAwA

Comment: It can be [41](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHG8ozMnFQFQyuF1IrUZAUlJaWlpSVpuhY3NfNsM20z8wpKSzQ0ucCKEjK1MhOidfOs8mKtMrVtDbkKijLzShQyIRoWw7UuWG7IZcRlzGUC4QIA) with standard input.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 7 bytes

```
Ḥ’⁵*Æ½‘
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuKTigJnigbUqw4bCveKAmCIsIjEww4figqwiLCIiLFsiIl1d)

```
Ḥ’⁵*Æ½‘  Main Link
Ḥ        Double
 ’       Decrement
  ⁵*     10 ^ that (smallest number with 2n digits)
    Æ½   Floor square root
      ‘  Increment
```

Square root + ceiling is one byte shorter but has floating point issues at n = 17 so Jonathan Allan provided a fix for +1 byte that avoids this issue.

Comment: ...and for no floating-point errors (which creep in at `n=17` I believe) 7 bytes - `Ḥ’⁵*Æ½‘` (since root ten is irrational we never increment when we shouldn't).

Comment: @JonathanAllan ah, I was worried that'd be an issue. thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
d‹↵√⌈
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJk4oC54oa14oia4oyIIiwiIiwiMTgiXQ==) or [verify the test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJAZjpufOKGkG4iLCJk4oC54oa14oia4oyIIiwiO1xuXG4yNSDJviDGmyA6IGAgLT4gYCBKICQgQGY7IFMgSiA7IOKBiyIsIiJd).

```
d‹↵√⌈
d     # Double
 ‹    # Decrement
  ↵   # 10 to the power of that
   √  # Sqrt
    ⌈ # Ceiling
```

Comment: Did you know there's a [300 rep bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22137/78850) you're eligible for?

Comment: yep, I just haven't posted it yet

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 19 bytes

```
\(n)10^(n-.5)%/%1+1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhabYzTyNA0N4jTydPVMNVX1VQ21DSEy64oTCwpyKjUMrQwNdNI0IYILFkBoAA)

Uses slight modification of the supplied formula.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

It outputs the sequence infinitely. Notably, this approach goes for efficiency without losing precision as a result of floating-point math.

```python
n=3
s=50
while 1:print-~n;n=n*5+s/n;s*=100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WmKvY1tSAqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0S3Ls86zzZPy1S7WD/PuljL1tDA4P9/AA)

#### Explanation

The sequence can be computed by taking the first \$ n \$ digits of \$ \sqrt{10} \$, rounded up. To do this efficiently, we can use the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method). By taking an arbitrary number \$ x \$, and repeatedly applying it to the recurrence \$ x = \frac{1}{2}(x + \frac{10}{x}) \$, we can obtain an approximation of \$ \sqrt{10} \$ that converges extremely quickly (with quadratic convergence).

The above formula can be translated in Python as `n=n/2+5/n`. This works fine to simply compute the square root, but to compute the sequence we must scale \$ n \$ by a factor of 10 after each iteration. This can be done by having another variable `s` as the "scale factor", and modifying our original formula to scale by `s`. We end up with the following formula:

```py
n=((n/s)/2+5/(n/s))*s*10; s*=10
```

It looks disgusting at first, but we can clean it up a bit:

```py
n=((n/s)/2+5/(n/s))*s*10;s*=10  ->
n=(n/s/2+5*s/n)*s*10;s*=10      ->
n=n/s/2*s*10+5*s/n*s*10;s*=10   ->
n=n*5+5*s/n*s*10;s*=10          ->
n=n*5+50*s*s/n;s*=10            ->
n=n*5+s/n;s*=100                (starting with s=50)
```

The only thing left to do now is to modify the formula to round *up*. This turns out to be pretty simple, only changing `n` to `n+1`. I've checked that the first 500 terms of the sequence exactly match the output, though in theory, it is still susceptible to rounding errors.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈×₂χＸχＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sRhIpGbmZOala4Rk5qYWawQXliYWpQbl55doGBpo6igE5JenFgGZOgqeeQWlJX6luUlAviYEWP//b2jwX7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Uses floating-point arithmetic. Explanation:

```
    χ       Predefined variable `10`
   ₂        Square root
  ×         Multiplied by
      χ     Predefined variable `10`
     Ｘ      Raised to power
       Ｎ    Input as a number
 ⌈          Ceiling
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

26 bytes using only integer arithmetic:

```
≔⁰ηＦＮ«≧×χηＷ﹪Ｌ×⊕η⊕η²≦⊕η»Ｉ⊕η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LCsIwFETXzVdkeQMRWrddiSvBiog/ENtrEsijJKkuxG@PgYioyxnOnBmVCKMXJudNjFo6aDlVrCdXHyjs3Lykw2IvGIAx@iDNIObKnbRUCc7aYuS0e4@au9IGKQx@WoyHPTqZVIWKawxo0SWcQDFOf3Mp1uXho//Gq/tJjkG7BFsR05@MsT7nrm3z6mZe) Link is to verbose version of code. 1-indexed. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η
```

Start with `0` as `⌊√1/10⌋`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
≧×χη
```

Multiply by 10 as our first estimate of `⌊10ⁱ·√1/10⌋`.

```
Ｗ﹪Ｌ×⊕η⊕η²≦⊕η
```

Increment our estimate until the number of digits of its square would become even, at which point it exactly equals `⌊10ⁱ·√1/10⌋`.

```
»Ｉ⊕η
```

Increment the final estimate, resulting in `⌈10ⁿ·√1/10⌉` as required.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

```c
f(n){n=exp10(n-.5)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDbboMwDH3vV1hIlUKBrcBaOmXsZdpXDB5QCB1qayqCNDTEry8zkGZrJF9yfHxkWwRHIbSuGLoDprK/hluGwcPO9UI@6ho7uBQ1MheGFdCbACJJ0cnyI4cUhicf4ogsTCa3j2cfmRAdTExskiQ22ycjn1VFg6oD8Vm0G/JSnGS7iDtZ/x5l/fMb2c7x4f8/dkx31bTApsFqLGVPbVtu0hdQ9bdsKnYb2X00wMYiHDxvZruz2LLmbVUktUXKg5DflRSVpqvdo5JQe5@5M/8jXFuiVMxZlxC8Avm1ypC2Qh@UbxdXaSpzIzuuRv0jqnNxVDr40sH58gs)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 17 bytes

```javascript
n=>-~(10**(n+.5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVBDkAwEAXQvVP85YwiLCyEuouUyoh0BLERrl7e5i3DNRxul@3Mg45T9DYG2@cvVWWaUjBFzRy97iCBRdlC0KH5M4ZxJ4DTcOg6FavOJBk8CXObPPED)

Works up to \$n=8\$.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 23 bytes

```javascript
n=>(p=10**(n+.5)+1)-p%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxDoMwDAXQnVP8BckmJSIDLJDeBdGkMkJxRBBL1bOnfcvb13st2yn56pO@Qo2@Jv@k7N3QdZSMHdk47nPratQTJPAYZggWuOm/MYxPA2yaih7BHvomeSCSMM/Nt/4A)

Works up to \$n=15\$.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(i=0n;!('0'+i*i)[2*n];)++i")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDsIwDADAva8wXWrXgApSp2A@ghiikiCjyEYt6oJ4e@h0w73iGpdp1vfnYP5INUs1uaY1Fmyzz6gyWNhhN3SsvdLt3Ns9ELO2VLcHNBA4BTC4CIybzATfBmByW7ykY/En2h4yGlFofvUP)

Don't try it at home.

Comment: [39](https://tio.run/##FckxDsIwDAXQvacwXWpjQDAwBXMRxBCVBAVF36hFXRBnD7A96T3iEudxKs/XFn5LLVuDndMSK/fZJy6GsOJhP2hZF7lAcQ2iWnppvyYGGR0QCHQyOv6hKvTuiEbH7DXtqt8ZG8oMkdB92hc)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·<°tî
```

Port of [*@hyper-neutrino♦*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245558/52210), so also outputs \$a(n)\$ based on \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0HabQxtKDq/7/98UAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX/MjVFTsKnMmo/IiDihpIgIj9O/8K3PMKwdMOu/8OvLP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
·      # Double the (implicit) input-integer
 <     # Decrease it by 1
  °    # Take 10 to the power this input*2-1
   t   # Take the square-root of that
    î  # Ceil it
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), 9 bytes

```
⌈10⋆-⟜0.5
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=U21hbGxlc3RfZXZlbl9kaWdpdF9zcXVhcmUg4oaQIOKMiDEw4ouGLeKfnDAuNQpTbWFsbGVzdF9ldmVuX2RpZ2l0X3NxdWFyZcKoIDHigL8y4oC/M+KAvzTigL814oC/NuKAvzfigL844oC/OeKAvzEw)

```
⌈           # ceiling of
 10⋆        # 10 to the power of
    -⟜0.5  # input minus 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
⌈`^10-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8eGOxYYG/x/1dCTEGRro6v3/DwA)

Uses formula: floor (`⌈`) of `10` to the power of (`^`) input minus (`-`) a half (`.`).

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
€D⁰mȯLd□N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr/23igoHhuKM1/@KCrETigbBtyK9MZOKWoU7//w)

Calculates the number of digits (`Ld`) of the square (`□`) of each (`mȯ`) number (`N`), and selects the index of the first (`€`) one that matches the input (`⁰`) doubled (`D`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
~n=ceil(10^(n-.5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7PNjk1M0fD0CBOI09Xz1RT879DcUZ@uYKhlaGBgl6NnULdfwA)

Based on the formula provided. By default, `ceil` returns a float, but `Int` can also be specified:

```julia
julia> f(n)=ceil(Int,10^(n-.5));

julia> map(f,1:10)
10-element Vector{Int64}:
          4
         32
        317
       3163
      31623
     316228
    3162278
   31622777
  316227767
 3162277661
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 6.5 bytes

```
+^^~-*$~~-2~
+          ~ Add 1 to
 ^       -2   floor of square root of
  ^~           10 to the power of
    -   ~       subtract 1 from
     * ~         multiply 2 with
      $           input
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCoNAFAX7OYdVwoLv76prk6NYCAkExEZt9yI220gaL-RtImg7w8z6G799P7ynnLdl_ri4P7suuUeRkrN0odvk4yUMT6CipiHSohIJGfIooArVqEERtViJnY1hHgvX5g8)